# Node.js/Axios/Cheerio Web Scraping - issue with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios, cheerio

I have an issue with part of my web scraping program. The
`return res.send(statsArray)` line in index.js always returns an empty array on the initial run (using npm start), and will only return a properly filled array after **at least** one refresh.

Here is relevant index.html (if needed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Web Scraping App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="src/app.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js, the file linked by index.html:

```
//Get players names, links, and stats
fetch('http://localhost:8000/players')
    .then(response => {return response.json()})
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
             
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Here is the relevant part of my index.js:

```
const PORT = 8000

const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())


app.listen(PORT , () => console.log(`server running on PORT ${PORT}`))

const players = 'https://www.trinethunder.com/sports/sball/2021-22/teams/trine?view=roster'
const playerStats = 'https://www.trinethunder.com'
const playerName = []
const playerLink = []


app.get('/players', (req, res) => {
    function getPlayers(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios(players)
            .then(response => {
                const html = response.data
                const $ = cheerio.load(html)
                //const error = false;
                $('td.text.pinned-col > a', html).each(function(){
                    var player = $(this).text()
                    player = player.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim();
                    //if name not yet in array, push to array
                    if(playerName.indexOf(player) === -1){
                        playerName.push(player)
                    } 
                })
                $('td.text.pinned-col > a', html).each(function(){
                    var link = $(this).attr('href')
                    //if link not yet in array, push to array
                    if(playerLink.indexOf(playerStats+link) === -1){
                        playerLink.push(playerStats+link)
                    } 
                })
                console.log(playerLink)
                
                /*if (!error){
                    resolve()
                } else {
                    reject('Error: something went wrong')
                }*/

            })
        })
    }
    function getPlayerStats(){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            for(let i=0; i<playerLink.length; i++){
                axios.get(playerLink[i])
                .then(response => {
                    const html = response.data
                    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
                    const statName = []
                    const statDesc = []
                    const statNum = []

                    $('h2 > span:nth-child(1)', html).each(function(){
                        var name = $(this).text()
                        statName.push(name)
                    })
                    $('.stat-title', html).each(function(){
                        var stat1 = $(this).text()
                        statDesc.push(stat1)
                    })
                    $('.stat-value', html).each(function(){
                        var stat2 = $(this).text()
                        statNum.push(stat2)
                    })
                    //Conditional is here because sometimes statsArray 
                    //gets filled multiple times 
                    if(statsArray.length <63){
                    statsArray.push(statName, statDesc, statNum)
                    }
                    
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
            return res.send(statsArray)
        }, 3000)
    }

getPlayers()
.then(getPlayerStats())
.catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

I have been trying to figure out how to loop through each url; using Promise.all, return new promise, async/await keywords, and so on. This approach has gotten me the closest to my desired outcome, but if there's a better way to do this please let me know.

I just need to be able to get the result on the first try. There must be something wrong with the way I'm using Promise; all the other data I scrape is returned without refreshing, and they don't use promises.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are passing the result of getPlayerStats into a then

Comment: @DanielA.White I changed that part to getPlayers().then(getPlayerStats), so it should just be passing the function now instead of the function result. But now I don't get any response, not even an empty array like I was earlier. When I check the network section of the browser console, it says the request is not finished yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to pull the data from the "https://www.trinethunder.com" site, because I get a 403 error from my IP, but in theory these corrections in the code should help. The only thing I don't understand is why you get playerName array if you don't use them.

```js
const PORT = 8000;

const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on PORT ${PORT}`));

const players = "https://www.trinethunder.com/sports/sball/2021-22/teams/trine?view=roster";
const playerStats = "https://www.trinethunder.com";

app.get("/players", (req, res) => {
  function getPlayers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios(players)
        .then((response) => {
          const playerName = [];
          const playerLink = [];
          const html = response.data;
          const $ = cheerio.load(html);
          //const error = false;
          $("td.text.pinned-col > a", html).each(function () {
            var player = $(this).text();
            player = player.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ").trim();
            //if name not yet in array, push to array
            if (playerName.indexOf(player) === -1) {
              playerName.push(player);
            }
          });
          $("td.text.pinned-col > a", html).each(function () {
            var link = $(this).attr("href");
            //if link not yet in array, push to array
            if (playerLink.indexOf(playerStats + link) === -1) {
              playerLink.push(playerStats + link);
            }
          });

          resolve(playerLink);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
  function getPlayerStats(playerLink) {
    const statsArray = [];
    setTimeout(async () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < playerLink.length; i++) {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios
            .get(playerLink[i])
            .then((response) => {
              const html = response.data;
              const $ = cheerio.load(html);
              const statName = [];
              const statDesc = [];
              const statNum = [];

              $("h2 > span:nth-child(1)", html).each(function () {
                var name = $(this).text();
                statName.push(name);
              });
              $(".stat-title", html).each(function () {
                var stat1 = $(this).text();
                statDesc.push(stat1);
              });
              $(".stat-value", html).each(function () {
                var stat2 = $(this).text();
                statNum.push(stat2);
              });
              //Conditional is here because sometimes statsArray
              //gets filled multiple times
              if (statsArray.length < 63) {
                statsArray.push(statName, statDesc, statNum);
              }
              resolve();
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        });
      }
      return res.send(JSON.stringify(statsArray));
    }, 3000);
  }

  getPlayers()
    .then(getPlayerStats)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: You're right, since I get the name in statsArray I can get rid of the playerName array. Thanks for the answer, it returns a properly filled array every time. However, the request can take up to 50 seconds to return the data. Guess I gotta figure that out now!